# I do want to refresh a page after form submission using php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form wherein user enters input.Then on submit click a modal popup triggers to confirm data.If user clicks submit in modal ,ajax post is done with alert message but the page doesn't get refreshed automatically and even form data remains as it is?
Even with window.reload() I tried.
Here is the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
        validate();
        $('#lname').text($('#lastname').val());
        $('#fname').text($('#firstname').val());
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'file.php',
            data: {
                fname: $("#fname").text(),
                lname: $("#lname").text()
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#confirm-submit").modal("hide");
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Inserted           Successfully</div>");
            }
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){ // hide alert message
        $("#result").fadeOut(); 
        //alert("hi deepak");
    }, 9000);
    window.reload();

    function validate(){
        var valid = $(".classinput").val();
        if (valid !== parseInt(valid, 10)) {
            //detects floating point numbers like 1.3 
            alert("Enter integer numbers");
        } else if (valid > -1) {
            // detects negative numbers
            alert("Enter positive numbers");
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to reload the page anyway then the point of making the AJAX request is completely redundant.

Comment: @Rory I want to save the data into DB as well that's why I am using ajax post.

Comment: That's fine, but you should either make a standard request to update the database and redirect in one call, or make the AJAX request as you are then update the DOM manually to the state you expect it to be in after the request is made.

Comment: ya i expect it to be after the request.

Comment: @Rory Hope you have got what i mean to say

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, then I think you should move your window.reload() into the success AJAX function like so if you want to refresh page after AJAX submit....

```
success: function(data){
    $("#confirm-submit").modal("hide");
    $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Inserted Successfully</div>");
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
```

Comment: tried with your comment but am getting console error as Uncaught TypeError: window.reload is not a function

Comment: Does jquery version matters. I am using src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"

Comment: try this  window.location.reload(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(data){
   if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
            $("#confirm-submit").modal("hide");
            $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Inserted Successfully</div>");
           setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 5000); 
   }
}
```